# twitter bootstrap-modal.js - end of a statement semi colons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just wondered if there was a reason why the twitter bootstrap-modal.js has so few end of a statement semi colons.

When I compress / minify the script, I run into interpreter issues.  I ran the script though JSLint and had no warnings about semi-colons.

Is it something to do with strict mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, aesthetics. Long answer, because it is valid (according to the devs). Your concern is actually part of a long debate with the developers of the bootstrap and the developer of JsMin. Currently is at a stalemate and cause for debate since the bootstrap guys claim that JsMin needs to be patched while the developer of JsMin claims it is their code that needs to be fixed. So you won't see a fix anytime soon.

Here is the thread over at GitHub over this matter:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3057

Note: Douglas Crockford is the developer of JsMin

Here is another thread over at reddit over the same issue:

http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/sag8p/crockford_on_bootstraps_semicolon_omission/

Comment: Funny, I clocked the debate late last night, I take Douglas Crockford's position I think as this wasted mine and other folks time.  Thanks for the links

Comment: @iancrowther yeah me too, but they're both being stubborn about it instead of just talking about it calmly. Though you can't dismiss Crockfords position, the dude is a heavyweight.

Comment: I have disagreed with Crockford in the past but normally whether a day, week or month later I normally come around to agreeing with him. That SOB is always right!!!  Commenting on this a year late but still very relevant.